# QtWidget background image issue (Qt Creator)

Tags: c++, css, qt, desktop

I want to add a background image to a Qt Widget. I am using Qt Creator 4.0.2 on Linux 64-bit.
The issue is when I am choosing a background image, it doesn't show (although a part of image can be seen around the PushButtons I have on page) when I run the program. However when choosing a background color works perfect.
(Using CSS)

Here are the screens :
[With background-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2hPp.png)
[With background-color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kowH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try and set it through the style sheet:

```
yourWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(<path-to-image>/image.png)")
```

It works for me.

Comment: Nope, it isn't working. I have a resource file setup and I am using that.
Is there any other way to set it up without using CSS ?

Comment: Well a brutal approach would be to set a QLabel underneath everything and make it show the image.

Comment: `QPixmap pic("../image.png");` and then use `label->setPixmap(pic);` where label is a pointer to the label. (You may need than to resize the image and stuff but it should work).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but I'm looking for more of a direct solution. As background-color works fine, so by that extension background-image should also work. Have you any experience with background-clip and origin ?

Comment: As I said, the simple setStyleSheet method works for me... I wouldn't know what to suggest right now